# MysqlDump command dont work in cron

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm, using this command to make backups with mysqldump:

```
sudo su
mysqldump  --defaults-file=/.confile.cnf -u USER  --all-databases | gzip > /backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz
```

But I want to automate it, so I add this on cron:

```
29 3 * * *  root  mysqldump  --defaults-file=/.confile.cnf -u USER  --all-databases | gzip > /backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz
```

But the problem is, when I execute the commands it works. But when I add this to cron, nothing happens.

Wrote I something wrong?Should I do it in other way?

I searched in others post, but I don't found a solution that works on that case.

There is the cron log:

```
Aug  4 13:15:01 ip-172-31-46-159 CRON[31590]: (root) CMD ( mysqldump  --defaults-file=/...
Aug  4 13:15:01 ip-172-31-46-159 CRON[31589]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: why do you have root written in the crontab ? try removing that !

Comment: I thought that there should be the user haha Thanks, I will try it :)

Comment: Hi again! I tried this, but nothing happens, cron ignore this if I delete "root".

Comment: I find a solution, but thanks for your help @MadhurBhaiya! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution:

I add mysqldump command on a script without changes:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump  --defaults-file=/.confile.cnf -u USER  --all-databases | gzip > /backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz
```

and I call this script from cron with the next line:

```
29 3 * * *  root /home/ubuntu/script.sh
```

and it works without problems.

NOTE: script.sh and confile.cnf should have 600 permissions (`chmod 600 /PATH`)

Comment: oh yeah ! now I remember, I do the same thing, by having mysqldump command in a bash file. In crontab, sometimes we use wget based commands to run some hyperlinks. In those cases we have to put the URL between double quotes ("), because of special characters like & in the URL, to pass GET parameters. Maybe try using double quotes ("), when you define mysqldump command directly in the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

crontab value should be

29 3 * * *  mysqldump  --defaults-file=/.confile.cnf -u UserNameGoesHereIfNotInDefaultsFile  --all-databases | gzip > /backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz

Comment: So the difference is only take off the "root",no?

Comment: you might have to include -U root in place of -u UserNameGoesHereIfNotInDefaultsFile

Comment: 29 3 * * *  mysqldump  --defaults-file=/.confile.cnf -u USER  --all-databases | gzip > /backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz  like that,no?

Comment: if your username is root and assuming the password it is the defaults file and the username is not then it would be - 29 3 * * * mysqldump --defaults-file=/.confile.cnf -u root --all-databases | gzip > /backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz

Comment: I tried but nothing happens. Do you want the log of cron? if I delete this root :"29 3 * * *  root  mysqldump", dont work.